# Can anyone solve this diode circuit with Thevenin theorem, please?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, thevenin, homework

[image: Image of question text]

The question says:

> Assuming that the diodes in the circuits of Fig. are ideal, utilize Thevenin's theorem to simplify the circuits and thus find the values of labeled currents and voltages.

Update:

I think that the solution is as shown below: Is it correct?

[image: Image of possible solution]

<sub>[Original image, before brightening/crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk1bT.jpg)</sub>

Comment: How about you try to solve it and show us where you get muddled. Also sort out the format of your question and embed the circuit picture properly. Engineering is all about getting the detail correct. Please do so for your question.

Comment: why are you dislike the post?if you dont interest just skip it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Don't just post a link. Remove that and show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: actually I worked a lot on this question and I searched a lot but I couldnt found any knowledge about how to solve diode circuits with thevenin theorem except this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bCNCIJRwPY&t=5s

Comment: That's great to hear. You'll find it easy to edit the question and vastly improve it, then, explaining in it everything you've understood so far on it. Please don't push the task back to people here, it's all on your shoulders. Look at other highly-voted questions on this site to see the standard that elicits help and guidance.

Comment: I just added a answer but ı dont know if it is true.

Comment: @mahmut - Hi, I have added your proposed solution into the question, as required for homework-type questions here, and fixed the syntax so that the question and proposed solution images display correctly. If you want to add new or improved images, please follow the syntax which you now see when you edit the question. It should be easier when using Ctrl+G on a desktop browser. (If possible, please also crop any images you add, to only the relevant part.) Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

[image: I did not apply to thevenin theorem in this solution. But the question clearly says solve with thevenin. How should I proceed when I need to solve with thevenin? I am curious about your feedback, please comment.]

[I solved it this way.]: https://i.[image]stack.imgur.com/qxEud.jpg

Comment: Hi, This answer isn't clear to me. Either (a) Are you writing it as an *answer*, because it really does answer your original question? In that case, please "accept" this answer (green "tick") to close the whole topic / question. Or (b) Are you mistakenly writing this as an *answer*, but in fact you still want replies / comments about it? In that case, this is an *update* and not an answer, and must be "edited into" your original question i.e. click "edit" under the question, add this update in a sensible place in the question, then delete this "answer". Which applies here, (a) or (b)?

Answer (score 0):

Both your answers are wrong. You didn't find V in the first question (as far as I can see) and the Thévenin voltage is wrong. Pay close attention to the signs.

Comment: thank you very much for your response sir,I will try one more time then.